# What is the best practice in select value from the input in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to know answer on this question.  Here is an example:

Code:

```
<input type='text' name='input_name' id='input_id' value='something'>
```

Comment: i am not able to get you

Comment: $("#input_id").val(); ...?

Comment: Why I have bad reputation, because I asked for help? :((

Comment: I think people have a problem with this question being too simple and that you have not shown things that you have tried already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$("input[type='text']").val() // CSS 3 kind a selectors:: used to loop through all the textboxes and perform operation

 **Or**

$("#input_id").val()
```

If you are having class added to your input you can use

```
$(".inputClass").val()
```

Id's can be multiple and unique, Note that IDs are the fastest selectors, and classes are slower than IDs

You may see the [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Your first line of code will *try* to extract all values from all text inputs.

Comment: Yeah Lix right i know that :) just to inform the OP to get idea about the best practice :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use [jQuery's built in `.val()` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

```
$( "#input_id" ).val();
```

You could also extract that attribute using the [`.attr()` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$( "#input_id" ).attr( "value" );
```

Comment: @use - If you are specifically looking for `value` you should use the function that is specifically for that. The `attr()` is used for any other attribute.

Comment: You can use `prop()` also instead `attr()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jQuery val() method to get the value from the input. See the jQuery API documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

ID is unique, so it will retrieve it fast compared to other method.

```
    $(function(){
        $('#input_id').val();
    })
```